# Define initial conditions for $u_x+u_y=u^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to find suitable initial conditions on $\partial\Omega$ for the partial differential equation $u_x+u_y=u^2$ on $\Omega$.

First I have solved the equation using the method of characteristics:

$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{u^2}$

From this I get:

$A=x-y$ and $B=y+u^{-1}$

Therefore: $u(x,y)=\frac{1}{f(x-y)-y}$.

Is there a specific way to find suitable initial conditions?

If I were to define $\Omega=\{y>0\}$ and $\partial\Omega=\{y=0\}$, then $u(x,0)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ where $f(x)\neq0$, would it be correct?

Comment: You also need to make sure that $\partial\Omega$ isn't a characteristic curve, since then $u$ won't be able to be specified outside of $\partial\Omega$ since information travels only along characteristics.